# How start service on boot using centos7?

Tags: service, init, centos7

I hava a service using installation as an init.d service (System V) on Centos 7.

I would like that after reboot the service starts automatically.

How can i do it?.

Thanks, I have tried:

```
1- /sbin/chkconfig --add my-service
2- /sbin/chkconfig --on my-service                    
3- chkconfig --list:my-service 0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on 6:off                                                          
4- /sbin/service my-service start                                         
5- reboot centos7                                                    
6- /sbin/service my-service status: Not running                          
The service does not start automatically
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct method with systemd is :

```
systemctl enable myservice
```

If it's a initv service you can use chkconfig anyway (maybe install it)

Comment: Thanks using chkconfig works fine, I had a little bug in my service.